# Unknown entity: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I ran into a problem while trying to make my program work using Vaadin and Spring-boot.
I am getting an IllegalArgumentException when trying to call EntityManager.persist() or EntityManager.merge()

So I managed to solve my previous problem following the instructions provided by someone here, which was a NullPointerException when trying to use my repository. I don't have that anymore, but I got a new one, an IllegalArgumentException.

I searched for the solution here, but most of the questions were about IllegalArgumentExceptions with user defined entities (like com.chinalbs.entity.Conductor for example), but mine is the following: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87
I read that it could be because of an @Entity annotation missing in one of my entity classes, but I have those, so thats not the case.
Tried to set @EntityScan for my entities package, but that didn't help either.

My Room entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Room")
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private int level;

    public Room() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
}
```

The part where I get the exception:

```java
@Transactional
@Component
public class Repository_Room_Impl implements Repository_Room{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Room> findAll() {
        return em.createQuery("select n from " + Room.class.getSimpleName() + " n").getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Room room) {
        em.persist(room);
    }

    public void delete(Room room) {
        em.remove(em.find(Room.class, room.getId()));
    }

    public void update(Room room) {
        em.merge(em);
    }

    public List<Course> getCourses(Room room)
    {
        List<Course> courses = em.createQuery("select n from " + Course.class.getSimpleName() + " n WHERE n.Room = :roomID", Course.class)
                .setParameter("roomID", room.getId())
                .getResultList();
        return courses;
    }
}
```

The stack trace:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:887)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.merge(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.beadando.repository.Impl.Repository_Room_Impl.update(Repository_Room_Impl.java:36)
    at com.example.beadando.repository.Impl.Repository_Room_Impl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$65e42158.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.example.beadando.repository.Impl.Repository_Room_Impl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c0f4ae10.update(<generated>)
    at com.example.beadando.component.Form_Room.updateRoom(Form_Room.java:94)
    at com.example.beadando.view.View_CRUD_Room.lambda$init$9b1b5227$1(View_CRUD_Room.java:54)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:205)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:373)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:264)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:420)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:420)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:59)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:64)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:387)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:368)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:368)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:310)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:89)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1507)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:242)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:901)
    ... 91 more
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error and stacktrace are quite helpful in this case: `Unknown entity: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87` means you're passing an object to the `EntityManager` that isn't an entity it knows about -- or isn't an entity at all.

The stacktrace also gives you the method name and line number of the offending line in `Repository_Room_Impl`:

```
em.merge(em);
```

Comment: That's right,  but according to this,  my guess was it doesn't recognize Room as an entity,  but I have my @Entity annotation there so I'm not sure how to make it find Room.

Comment: Change the line `em.merge(em)` so that it references a `Room`.